# async await for function inside assignment

Tags: javascript, async-await, indexeddb

this is my code

```
const openDb = async() => {
  var db: IDBDatabase;
    var request =  await indexedDB.open("adminDB");
     request.onsuccess = (event: any) => {
      db =  event.target.result;
    };
    return db;
}
```

what i'm trying to do is to await for `db =  event.target.result;` to be done before `return db;`
how can i do that? i know basicly how async/await works for functions but it does not seem to be the same for this situation. any help plz

Comment: You will find it much easier to use a wrapper library that uses promises. You are using `await` but `indexedDB.open()` doesn't even return a promise which makes it pointless to use `async/await` here

Comment: you can use promise in this case in resolve db inside request.onsuccess, I believe this should do the trick

Comment: Some of the possible wrapper libraries are mentioned in MDN docs. Others are easy to search for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB

Comment: check out [idb](https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb)

Comment: @charlietfl i really prefer to use core indexedDB, bad habit i know but i prefer core things

Comment: @AbdelrahmanHussien i will give it a shot. thank u

Comment: Ok, just going to be more time consuming and tedious using the native API directly when using a well documented lib like dexie.js makes it much easier